# NGINX as warm cache in front of wowza for HLS live streams - Get per stream data duration and data transferred?

Tags: nginx, caching, statistics, http-live-streaming, wowza

I've setup NGINX as a warm cache server in front of Wowza > HTTP-Origin application to act as an edge server.  The config is working great streaming over HTTPS with nDVR and adaptive streaming support.  I've combed the internet looking for examples and help on configuring NGINX and/or other solutions to give me live statistics (# of viewers per stream_name) as well parse the logs to give me stream duration per stream_name/session and data_transferred per stream_name/session.  The logging in NGINX for HLS streams logs each video chunk.  With Wowza, it is a bit easier to get this data by reading the duration or bytes transferred values from the logs when the stream is destroyed...   Any help on this subject would be hugely appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx isn't aware of what the chunks are.  It's only serving resource to clients over HTTP, and doesn't know or care that they're interrelated.  Therefore, you'll have to derive the data you need from the logs.

To associate client requests together as one, you need some way to track state between requests, and then log that state.  Cookies are a common way to do this.  Alternatively, you could put some sort of session identifier in the request URI, but this hurts your caching ability since each client is effectively requesting a different resource.

Once you have some sort of session ID logged, you can process those logs with tools such as Elastic Stack to piece together the reports you're looking for.

Depending on your goals with this, you might find it better to get your data client-side.  There, you have a better idea of what a session actually is, and then you can log client-side items such as buffer levels and latency and what not.  The HTTP requests don't really tell you much about the experience the end users are getting.  If that's what you want to know, you should use the log from the clients, not from your HTTP servers.  Your HTTP server log is much more useful for debugging underlying technical infrastructure issues.

Comment: Thank you for the info!  It is much appreciated!  I've started investigating how to derive the data I'm looking for client side! :) Tim